# Wavesurfer Plugin usage in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wavesurfer.js

I'm using [wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) with React and Typescript. To get the typings I'm also using the corresponding [@types/wavesurfer.js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/wavesurfer.js). Now I want to use the [cursor plugin](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/cursor/index.html). When I'm importing the actual CursorPlugin this way

```
import CursorPlugin from 'wavesurfer.js/src/plugin/cursor.js';
```

I get all the type hints etc. but the compiler says:

```
ERROR in ./path/to/my/component/index.tsx 9:0-62
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'wavesurfer.js/src/plugin/cursor.js' in 'path/to/my/component'
```

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-khorana-is04t4?file=/src/App.tsx) demonstrating this behavior.

I already found a workaround on the interwebs:

```js
import CursorPlugin from 'wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.cursor.min.js';
```

and it works although I don't get type hints this way. But it just doesn't seem to be the "right" way to do it, so I was wandering if anyone else has found any  better solution yet?